# VC++ 6.0 Компилятор

Tags: visual-c++

Производительность кода зависит от того, как он скомпилирован, вопрос в том, можно ли и каким образом подключить к VC++ 6.0 более современный компилятор!? Где его взять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соглашусь с student, VC++ всего лишь среда для разработки.
Компиляторы можно взять отсюда:

- [GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection](http://gcc.gnu.org/)
- [Minimalist GNU for Windows](http://www.mingw.org/)
- [Intel Compiler Suite](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compilers/)

Comment: Ну, а к примеру, если я предполагаю использовать код на процессоре intel i7, использование компилятора Intel Compiler Suite даст преимущества перед другими?

Comment: А какое преимущество и в каких количествах Вы хотите получить?

Comment: Возможно и получите, но для этого придется основательно изучить компилятор. В большинстве задач этого не требуется

Comment: Для примера - итерационное перемножение матриц размером 1000х1000

Comment: Чтобы проверить, нужно написать программу на каком-нибудь языке программирования, лучше всего си подойдет, потом посмотреть ассемблерный код от разных компиляторов и сравнить по некоторым критериям. Тут целым рефератом пахнет. Слишком много работы :-)

Comment: Одним словом для быстрого кода нужно перебираться на ассемблер!? В общем случае да или не совсем!? Или имеет смысл подключить математические библиотеки от Intel - mkl, думаю, что программисты из Intel разбираются в оптимизации кода для своих процессоров!? :)

Comment: перебравшись на ассемблер вы по-тихоньку начнете сходить с ума)
Си с Intel'овскими библиотеками должно хватить для решение задач.

Comment: @rejie Обычно, когда встает вопрос об оптимизации, рекомендую поступать следующим образом:
1) разрабатывате приложение на подходящем высокоуровневом языке(например с/с++)
2) добиваетесь того чтоб оно правильно работало(желательно обложить его юнит-тестами и автоматическим регрессионными тестами)
3) после этого профилируете приложение с целью найти ботелнеки(самы часто вызываемые функции, места кода в которых приложение проводит больше всего времени и т.п. чуствительные места)
4) для каждого найденого ботелнека надо решить что с ним делать
5) для некоторых из них подойдут ассемблерные вставки

Comment: Для некоторых ботлнеков могут подойти целые ассемблерные функции в отдельных файлах, для некоторых мест нужно будет улучшение/изменение алгоритма/логики работы (и это происходит чаще чем обращение к ассемблеру). Плюс ко всему этому вам надо будет разработать какую-нибуть систему для измерения целевых показателей производительности(а не поиска ботлнеков, ведь у Вас же есть цель с которой вы проводите оптимизацию, и под эту цель некоторые ботелнеки могут просто не подходить, грубо говоря некоторые не будут влиять на целевые показатели).

Comment: хех, как вывод, компилятор может что-то и оптимизирует, но остальная оптимизация через директивы компилятора и ассемблерные вставки полностью ложится на ваши плечи :-D

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос, конечно интересный, но возникает встречный вопрос: зачем прикручивать компилятор к студии?

Полноценную замену среды получить скорее всего не удастся. Ведь на этом пути стоит много проблем:

- совместимость дебаг-инфы с дебагером винды(в том числе дебаговый парсинг STL - это даже в разных версиях студии не одинаково);
- совместимость вывода ошибок компилятора(больше не будет двойного клика);
- настройки проекта перестанут быть визуальными));
- вообще сами файлы проекта вы не сможете просто так передать другому компилятору(и кстати мне не известно место, где в студии можно указать путь к компилятору))), а даже если бы и было такое место, то встречный вопрос: у нас типа что все компиляторы на командлайн одни и те же опции принимают???);
- остается конечно вариант с разными build-step-ами, но тут опять же встречный вопрос: зачем? build-step-ы не для этого придумывали.

Так что на мой взгляд: makefile + commandline будет самым разумным. А студия - это не среда - а текстовый редактор)))(в данном случае). Будучи дополнена VisualAssist-oм, на мой взгляд лучший редактор. Дебагер конечно жалко не работет на кросстулчейнах).

Comment: Ну что вы. Где уж ей быть лучшим редактором ;) Груз истории не повзолит ей стать таковой. Что же до Intel Compiler, то у интела есть ещё такая штука, как пакет интеграции компилятора в студию. Когда-то давно имел с ним дело. Тогда можно будет просто выбрать компилятор, которым надо собирать приложение. И отладка работает и всё что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

> Производительность кода зависит от того, как он скомпилирован, вопрос в том, можно ли и каким образом подключить к VC++ 6.0 более современный компилятор!? Где его взять?

Все непросто.

1. VS - это среда. Следовательно, существует возможность подключения сторонних компиляторов. Выше уже приводился пример Intel C++ Compiler, который интегрируется в среду.
2. VS - это среда. Следовательно, никто не мешает ее использовать как редактор, а сборку осуществлять внешними средствами. Например, make + gcc.
3. VS - это среда. Компилятор по отношению к ней является ВНЕШНИМ исполняемым файлом. В теории никто не мешает переписать сам файл компилятора файлом от более новой версии среды. Напоминаю, что для сборки C-кода в MSVS используется компилятор CL.EXE (Microsoft C/C++ Language Compiler). Лежит он где-то во внутренностях каталога Program Files. Точно не помню, но сами в состоянии найти.
4. Опять буду банален :-) VS имеет возможность задать в свойствах проекта вызов любого исполняемого файла на любой файл исходника. При этом почти наверняка теряется куча возможностей (переход по ошибкам в редакторе к месту ошибку, PCH, приколы с отладчиком и т.д.)
   К тому же отмечу, что у меня в студии часто ломался intellisense. В том плане, что нужно соблюдение кучи условий, чтобы он нормально работал (include только через <> для стандартных файлов и "" для файлов проекта, четко заданные каталоги к include/lib'ам, файлы строго определенной кодировки (ага, без Unicode))

Т.е. итог - если Вы сильны духом - берите нормальный текстовый редактор, учитесь пользоваться консольными средствами разработки (компиляторы + make/build).
Если же фанат продукции M$ - переползайте на MS VS 2010. Она того стоит.

Answer (score 0):

VC++ - это всего навсего IDE; ответ - да, можно. Компилятор загружается из интернета, к примеру, с сайта майкрософт. Далее поменять в настройках VC++ путь к компилятору.

Answer (score 0):

скачайте [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/)
Она распространяется бесплатно и пишите в свое удовольствие.

Comment: А что это за зверь? На нём можно писать полноценные приложения?

Comment: Встроенный в него компилятор работает без ограничений?

Comment: Не знаю насчет встроенного компилятора, но IDE из коробки с компилятором, а компилятор самый последний от MS.